# How to enable "Go to declaration" from typescript to json (i18next)

Tags: json, typescript, intellij-idea, find, i18next

Im working on a project that uses i18next with react and typescript, where translationkeys are defined in .json files.

One drawback of switching to json for the translation files, is that we can no longer use the intellij idea "Go to declaration" or ctrl + left-click feature, to quickly navigate from a key usage in typescript, to its declaration in the json file.

Is there any way to enable this without requiring all developers to download some third-party intellij plugin?

I've googled for hours for any information about this.

I've made a d.ts file to enable strong typing for where translationkeys are used. What strikes me as odd is that intellij/typescript is able to know when a key doesent exist and warns about it, but at the same time doesent know "where" that key exists whenever i type a correct key.

I also set resolveJsonModule:true in tsconfig, but to my limited understanding it doesent seem relevant.

Comment: You could create a feature request for it at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not technically possible because commands like `Go To Declaration` will look for a declaration in a **source code file** (think `.ts` or `.js` or `.d.ts`) whereas you want to go *...to its declaration in the **json** file.*

The `resolveJsonModule` flag won't help you either because as per [the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#resolveJsonModule):

> Allows importing modules with a ‘.json’ extension, which is a common practice in node projects. This includes generating a type for the import based on the static JSON shape.

One possible solution is to create a build script to take your `.json` file and output a `.js` or `.ts` file containing the same content, then IDE commands like `Go To Declaration` will jump to that file.

In summary: you will need some kind of plugin, or a custom build script.

**DISCLAIMER:** I don't use `i18next` or `react`, this answer is based on my understanding of both TypeScript and the JetBrains Rider IDE (which is like IntelliJ).